# Mysql query into CSV and one field split

Tags: mysql, csv, split

I have this code, but something wrong with it:

```
SELECT email, realname INTO OUTFILE "c:/mydata.csv"
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(realname, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as firstname,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(realname, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as lastname,
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
FROM mytable;
```

I select only the email and realname fields and split realname into 2 fields when I encounter a space!

Error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(realname, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as firstname, SUBST' at line 2
```

Comment: Error messages? Sample data? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INTO OUTFILE` must be at the end.

```
SELECT email, realname 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(realname, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as firstname,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(realname, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as lastname,
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
FROM mytable
INTO OUTFILE "c:/mydata.csv";
```

[See manual entry.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)